# Selenium not working with opera

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I'm creating a program to go into my router and adjust settings, and to do it from different browsers, I've got FF, Chrome, and IE to work. Everything I try with Opera won't work. It only opens up two tabs, one with 127.0.0.1:some_crazy_port# and file:///C:/Users/EETEST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/opera4672404649060883314profile/
When I'm trying to get to, 192.168.0.1

System: Windows 7: Eclipse Kepler & Selenium 2.37.0

Here's my code:

```
import com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class NewTest extends SeleneseTestCase {

private WebDriver cDriver;
private String baseUrl;


    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        baseUrl = "192.168.0.1";//Heres the destination
        System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Opera");
        cDriver = new OperaDriver();//Setting up the OperaDriver
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        try{
            cDriver.navigate().to(baseUrl);//Go!
            //Thread.sleep(5000);//Everything below is just doing stuff on the page
            cDriver.findElement(By.id("radioButtonssBasic")).click();
            Select selector = new Select(cDriver.findElement(By.id("ap")));
            selector.selectByValue("0SSIDisNAMED"+router);
            cDriver.findElement(By.name("passphrase1")).sendKeys(routerPass);
            cDriver.findElement(By.name("passphrase2")).sendKeys(routerPass);
            cDriver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(user);
            cDriver.findElement(By.name("password1")).sendKeys(userPass);
            cDriver.findElement(By.name("password2")).sendKeys(userPass);
            cDriver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
        }finally{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        cDriver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: Last time I used selenium with Opera it was not behaving properly. Guess they never fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For **Opera versions below 12**, use `OperaPrestoDriver`
https://github.com/operasoftware/operaprestodriver

For **Opera versions** **above 12**, use `operachromiumdriver`
https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Opera are you using? [As far as I understand](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver) the `OperaDriver` won't support any Opera versions > 12.x.

> Current implementation of OperaDriver supports only 12.x and older versions of Opera browser (based on Presto engine) and does not support newer versions (based on Blink engine).

Since Opera dropped the WebKit engine and started using Google's Blink engine, I assume there has to be another driver to support Opera.

I'm currently searching for a solution myself, so I don't really know if there is one yet.